# FatalError: error TS6046: Argument for '--moduleResolution' option must be: 'node', 'classic', 'node16', 'nodenext'

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm creating a next.js web application using typescript and tailwind CSS. I run `yarn dev` in my command line and I'm getting the following error:

`FatalError: error TS6046: Argument for '--moduleResolution' option must be: 'node', 'classic', 'node16', 'nodenext'.`

I tried to reinstall my packages and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Go to tsconfig.json file

Update this or add this :-

```html
"moduleResolution": "node",
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],

 "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "*/.ts",
    "*/.tsx",
    ".next/types/*/.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone. I had the same error when trying to use `"moduleResolution": "bundler"` in my tsconfig.json with Typescript 4 installed. Updating Typescript to `^5.3.3` fixed the issue.